# storing images in xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, image

I am new to XML. I have an XML document that I am inserting data manually. I wanted to know if it is possible to include an image in an XML file and not by using the file path. I have found something about encoding but I do not understand how this work and the option is not even available in the XML editor. After storing the images in the XML file, I will access it using javascript. Please provide further information on this matter.

Comment: Use base64 encode of image content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: @Justinas..partly as in this case javascript is being used however I want to do it manually

Comment: So use JS and output content or just use some other tool. E.g. https://www.urlencoder.org/

Comment: @Justinas...thank you for your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image is binary data, and the usual way to store binary data in an XML document is by encoding it in base64 (which turns it into ASCII characters). Libraries to convert from binary to base64, and back, are widely available, but the details depend very much on your programming environment. There are also online services where you can upload an image and get back its base64 representation: an example is here https://www.base64encode.net/base64-image-encoder

Comment: ..Thank you, that was helpful and cleared my doubts